# Input and objects invoking their own methods

Tags: java, methods, input

I need to know if I understand this. In this program the variable "input" is created as a Scanner object and therefore can access Scanner methods. Is this inheritance? Second, it is not until the assignment of "radius" as a double datatype and use of nextDouble method that the actual input from a user occurs. Do I have this correct? If you're making objects from Scanner, why can't you just use Scanner directly?

```
 public class ComputeAreaWithConsoleInput {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

// Create a Scanner object

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    //Scanner object called "input" created


System.out.print("Enter a number for radius: ");
double radius = input.nextDouble();        // "input" set as double datatype


double area = radius * radius * 3.14159;


System.out.println("The area for the circle of radius " +
radius + " is " + area);
   }
}
```

Comment: No its not inheritance. You can only access static methods directly. And the actual input from user occurs when the user presses enter after entering whatever double value they entered which then gets assigned to the double variable you declared.

Comment: `why can't you just use Scanner directly?` No particular reason. It could be implemented statically. It is more convenient the way it is now.

Answer (score 0):

> In this program the variable "input" is created as a Scanner object and therefore can access Scanner methods. Is this inheritance?

No, it is not [inheritance.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) This does not define a subtype of `Scanner`. `input` is an **instance** of `Scanner`.

> It is not until the assignment of "radius" as a double datatype and use of nextDouble method that the actual input from a user occurs. Do I have this correct?

Again, no. This particular `Scanner` reads from standard input. Writes to a steam and reads from that stream are decoupled and can have absolutely nothing to do with each other. Reading a stream will block if there is no data to read. The read *waits* until the user has typed something.

> If you're making objects from Scanner, why can't you just use Scanner directly?

This is a nonsensical question.